# query by has many relation where all children must meet the conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel, relation

query with hasMany relation if all children must meet the requirements

for example all products that hasMany pictures where all status = 1 in pictures relation

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more details of your problem to get best solution. Although you can try something like

```
Poroduct::has('pictures')->where('status', true);
```

or

```
$products = Poroduct::has('pictures');
 $products->where('pictures', function($query){
              $query->  // some conditions
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

[This Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) explains querying relationships. The first example is probably what you are looking for.

You could try

```
$products->pictures()->where('status', 1)->get();
```

Comment: While This May Answer The Question, It Is Always Better To Explain What The Code Provided Does As The Future Readers May Not Be Having The Exact Database Structure.